# How do people change the odometer reading?

Tags: odometer

I am a fan of getting a steal deal out of used cars. But most dealers out there usually mess with the odometer reading. While there are multiple technical ways to determine the age and condition of a vehicle (most of which I am not aware of), the easiest way for every person is to cross check the odometer and service history of the vehicle.

The issue with service history is that most people don't tend to do their service at authorized service centers (at least in India) and that too not as per the norms set by company. So, there won't be any records maintained after the first few years. So, I guess most people inspect the places where such used car dealers make mistakes such as the wear on the pedals, seat cover condition, rust formation etc. But often I have heard that tampering with digital odometer is hard. At least harder than the analog ones. Based on that I have a few questions.

1. But how does the new odometer technology work?
2. Is odometer reading stored in instrument cluster memory? If so, is it programmable by third party people? Again, how easy is to change the readings on instrument cluster?
3. Additionally, does ECU store this information? If so, does ECU check the odometer reading on the instrument cluster against the value stored in ECU?
4. Finally, is it easy to tamper the odometer reading stored in ECU by third party people?

Comment: I can't resist the urge to nitpick here. All odometers are digital; old ones are mechanical and new ones are usually electronic.

Comment: @TannerSwett Well - "digital" meaning "there are digits printed on the wheels", but I would argue the mechanism itself is analog. But this is kind of beside the point :D

Comment: @Steve So we are still using mechanical mechanism rather than electronics for odometer? I thought modern ones were electrical type using optical/magnetic recorders like the crankshaft position sensor.

Comment: When I say the "old ones are not digital", I was referring to your comment about "all are digital". Depends on your definition of "digital" - which to me means "a set number of individual states that cannot be confused with each other", but the wheels on older odometers, while they DO have digits printed on them, are not digital, as they continuously rotate through the 10 values and all intermediate values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how does the new odometer technology work?

Not sure what you're asking. Basically, you drive ... the vehicle recognizes how far you've driven ... it records the ticks and translates it to mileage and stores the information.

> Is odometer reading stored in instrument cluster memory?

It is my understanding the odometer reading is stored in several places, such as the ECU, instrument cluster, and other places.

> If so, is it programmable by third party people?

Yes, it can be.

> Again, how easy is to change the readings on instrument cluster?

With the right equipment, it's very easy.

> Additionally, does ECU store this information? If so, does ECU check the odometer reading on the instrument cluster against the value stored in ECU?

This type of information is the type which the vehicle manufacturer doesn't really publicize. People have reversed engineered it to understand how it works and how the information is stored. They then devise ways to put new values into the storage places so the dash shows a better for them (lower mileage) situation than is actual. I've heard rumor that some of the reprogrammers which can be obtained to change the odometer don't do it in all the places within the vehicle, so sooner or later the system catches up with the reading and will change the odometer to the correct mileage. Unfortunately, this is well after the vehicle has been sold and is out and on its way. IOW: Buyer be ware.

> Finally, is it easy to tamper the odometer reading stored in ECU by third party people?

I think your other question is pretty much the same as this, so I'll answer it the same: With the right tools, it's very easy.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, considering the widespread odometer tampering, wouldn't it be easy for the manufacturers to lock down the ECU memory or other storages which stores such data using a strong password which is unique to that hardware. And making sure that those passwords are only available to manufacturers. This would make it a bit more costly and harder for these mechanics to tamper the odometer data.

Comment: @AbhishekPG - Don't think it's the mechanics who are doing this. It's the shady vehicle resalers. I'm not saying mechanics *don't* do it, but the reason it's getting done is to sell a car for more than it is worth. As far as manufacturers lokcing it out, they pretty much do it now, not with passwords, but with other methods. And what happens? People figure out ways around it. Besides, a password would become compromised in no time flat, so it wouldn't make much difference anyways. Someone from the manufacturer would sell it to make some quick money.

Comment: @AbhishekPG - The best bet when buying a vehicle is to purchase it from a reputable source. They are going to be less likely to sell a car which has been tampered with. Also, inspecting the car for tell tales it has more mileage than what is on the odometer is good. Things like worn rubber brake pedal If it shows, there's probably quite a bit of mileage on it. IOW: Buyer be ware.